# Get a list of valid time zones in Go

Tags: go, timezone

I'd like to write a method that will populate a Go Language array with the common timezones that are accepted by the `time.Format()` call, for use in an HTML template (Form select to allow them to read and choose their timezone).  Is there a common way to do this?

Comment: `func (t Time) Format(layout string)` doesn't take a time zone (other than "MST" to indicate where you want the time zone to go in the output).

Comment: The documentation for [time.LoadLocation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#LoadLocation) describes where Go looks for time zone information.

Comment: If you can call a C++ library I can show how to do this.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To get a list of time zones, you can use something like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

var zoneDirs = []string{
    // Update path according to your OS
    "/usr/share/zoneinfo/",
    "/usr/share/lib/zoneinfo/",
    "/usr/lib/locale/TZ/",
}

var zoneDir string

func main() {
    for _, zoneDir = range zoneDirs {
        ReadFile("")
    }
}

func ReadFile(path string) {
    files, _ := os.ReadDir(zoneDir + path)
    for _, f := range files {
        if f.Name() != strings.ToUpper(f.Name()[:1]) + f.Name()[1:] {
            continue
        }
        if f.IsDir() {
            ReadFile(path + "/" + f.Name())
        } else {
            fmt.Println((path + "/" + f.Name())[1:])
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
Africa/Abidjan
Africa/Accra
Africa/Addis_Ababa
Africa/Algiers
Africa/Asmara
Africa/Asmera
Africa/Bamako
Africa/Bangui
...
```

Comment: Fantastic!  Though, I think there is a typo in `ReadFile("")` -- Shouldn't it be `ReadFile(zoneDir)`?

Comment: Nope, no typo) It is because of recursion. Also it is more like prototype, so you can refine and integrate somewhere, but you probably need to store results instead of just printing.

Comment: Any idea how to include the default fallback data located inside of `$GOROOT/lib/time`?

Comment: In MacOS 11, there is a file `+VERSION` in `/usr/share/zoneinfo/`. You have to skip this file.

Comment: There are some files in directories which are not TZ files on macOS and on some Linux distros.
The best way to test it is to try load the zone with `time.LoadLocation()` and check for errors. If no error, the file is TZ file.

`if _, err := time.LoadLocation(tzFilename); err != nil { continue }`

Comment: @jeremiah.trein I’m not sure if such a solution deserves a full-fledged answer, so would rather use comments section. Here you can have a look at how I extracted the strings from `$GOROOT/lib/time`: https://github.com/esimonov/locache/blob/main/cache_test.go. Heavily influenced by the internals of `time` package.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example: https://play.golang.org/p/KFGQiW5A1P-

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strings"
    "unicode"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(GetOsTimeZones())
}

func GetOsTimeZones() []string {
    var zones []string
    var zoneDirs = []string{
        // Update path according to your OS
        "/usr/share/zoneinfo/",
        "/usr/share/lib/zoneinfo/",
        "/usr/lib/locale/TZ/",
    }

    for _, zd := range zoneDirs {
        zones = walkTzDir(zd, zones)

        for idx, zone := range zones {
            zones[idx] = strings.ReplaceAll(zone, zd+"/", "")
        }
    }

    return zones
}

func walkTzDir(path string, zones []string) []string {
    fileInfos, err := ioutil.ReadDir(path)
    if err != nil {
        return zones
    }

    isAlpha := func(s string) bool {
        for _, r := range s {
            if !unicode.IsLetter(r) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }

    for _, info := range fileInfos {
        if info.Name() != strings.ToUpper(info.Name()[:1])+info.Name()[1:] {
            continue
        }

        if !isAlpha(info.Name()[:1]) {
            continue
        }

        newPath := path + "/" + info.Name()

        if info.IsDir() {
            zones = walkTzDir(newPath, zones)
        } else {
            zones = append(zones, newPath)
        }
    }

    return zones
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go's time pkg uses a [timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) database.

You can load a timezone location like this:

```
loc, err := time.LoadLocation("America/Chicago")
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

t := time.Now().In(loc)
```

The `Format` function is not related to setting the time zone, this function takes a fixed reference time that allows you to format the date how you would like. Take a look at the time pkg [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/time/).

For instance:

```
fmt.Println(t.Format("MST")) // outputs CST
```

Here is a running [example](https://play.golang.org/p/lZMCN7t34o)

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. Why is it so much upvoted.

Comment: The questions is a bit unclear. The question mistakes how the `Format` method works. This answer explains how to load the correct location and display the time using the loaded location. Displaying a list in an html template seems to be the easy part, so I assume people find what wrote useful, hence the upvotes.