# How can I validate a timezone?

Tags: go

I have a string that represents a timezone, but I need to validate it. For example:

```
timeZone := "ABC-3"
```

Is there a method in golang to validate it? Or some external library?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to validate timezone at the backend which is coming from the frontend in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46400479/i-want-to-validate-timezone-at-the-backend-which-is-coming-from-the-frontend-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to abbreviations or codes like `GMT`, `CET`, `PST`, `UTC-7`, `GMT+3`, Go natively doesn't support loading locations with these abbreviations and codes.

You can use the `time.LoadLocation` function to try to load different locations, but you would need to use the names of the timezones defined in [IANA Time Zone Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). A couple of examples:

- `UTC` - for loading the UTC time zone location
- `Local` - represents the system's local time zone
- `America/Chicago`, `Europe/Sarajevo`, `Asia/Shanghai`, `Africa/Accra`, etc. - for loading corresponding time zones

If you provide an invalid time zone to the `time.LoadLocation` function, you will get an error.

```
timeLoc, err := time.LoadLocation("ABC-3")
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Output:

```
unknown time zone ABC-3
```

To get a list of all valid time zones, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40120056/get-a-list-of-valid-time-zones-in-go) answer.

If you really need, for some reason, to use the abbreviations like `UTC-7` in your code, you can always create your own location and use it throughout your code. Example:

```
loc := time.FixedZone("UTC-7", -7*60*60)
```

You can find more details [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-time-zone-function-in-golang-with-examples).

There are some packages like [go-timezone](https://godoc.org/github.com/tkuchiki/go-timezone), that can help you extract time zone location info from time zone codes like `CET`, `PST`, `GMT`, etc. In my opinion, there are a couple of things to be aware of when using it:

- Some time zone codes like `BST` can return an `ErrAmbiguousTzAbbreviations` error, which means that there are multiple timezones using the same time zone code.
- The relation info on time zone codes and time zone locations is maintained and updated by the contributors and maintainers of the package (hardcoded).